# nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... MySQL, ReactJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

Trying to login in ReactJS app using nodejs, express.js and mysql. Here Registration is working but problem is occurring during login. Here is my code for login

```
function Login(){
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [pass, setPass] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const login = () => {
        Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/login", {
            email: email,
            pass: pass
        }).then(()=>{
            navigate('/info');
        })
    }

    return(
        <div className='container__login'>
            
           <div className="content__login">
             <FontAwesomeIcon  icon={faCircleUser} size={'2x'}/>  
            <h1 >LOGIN</h1>
            <form>
               <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser}/> <input type= "email" name="email" placeholder='email' id="email__login"
               onChange={(e) => {
                   setEmail(e.target.value)
               }}
               /><br/>
               <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faKey}/> <input type= "password" name="pass" placeholder='password' id='pass__login'
               onChange={(e) => {
                   setPass(e.target.value)
               }}
               />
                <button className="btn__login" onClick={login}>Login</button>                
            </form>
        </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');
const { response } = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const path = require('path');

const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'travel'
});
app.use(cors());

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))

//Login
app.post("/api/login", (req,res)=> {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const pass = req.body.pass;

    if(email && pass){
        db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND pass = ?', [email, pass],(err, result) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            if(result.lenght > 0){
                req.session.loggedin = true;
                req.session.email = email;
                response.redirect('/info');
            }else{
                response.send('Incorrect email and/or password!');
            }
            response.end();
        });
    }else{
        response.send('Please enter email and password');
        response.end();
    }

});

app.listen(3001, ()=>{
    console.log('running on port 3001');
});
```

Here is the error
[image]

I tried to follow other solutions for this. But cannot able to solve this problem. It's working while registration. But doesn't work for login.

Comment: There is a bug in your function and it's make your app crash, try console.log one by one line of code to find error, especially the function when you call that error appears

Comment: Lots of references to `response` in your code,  but that variable doesn't exist!